Set HostName only using Dual DHCP DNS Server
I have a small network where I run Dual DHCP DNS Server on one of the devices.
I would like all other devices to use dynamic IP addresses, but still be able to define the hostnames of those (centrally in the configuration file of the DHCP/DNS server, not on the devices themselves). Then I wouldn't need to care about the IP addresses, but would still be able to access the devices using the known hostnames.
Does anyone know how to configure this? As far as I see, as soon as one wants to explicitly set the hostname in the configuration, one has to use the static host section, and one needs to explicitly state an IP-address for the MAC-address, otherwise the device won't get any IP.
